# EOFError (end of file reached)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not really sure what is going on with my rails app. I have not changed any code on my front page but I am getting the error EOFError (end of file reached) with no further information on the logs.

It is only the index page that has this issue. I would like to know, if there is any other way I can get more information on this error.

This is all I have from papertrail
[image]

**Edit:** In localhost everything works fine but once I have deployed to Heroku my frontpage does not work.

Comment: Show full error trace from `/log/production.log` and your controller/view for frontpage.

Answer (score 0):

After a back and forth with Heroku, my issue ended up being resolved. There was no error in the code as this piece of code had been working all along. Heroku advised that maintenance occurs every night and maybe the moving of the app to a different dyno might have resolved the issue.

If anyone else ends up with a similar issue, if a restart does not fix it maybe ask Heroku to move you to a different dyno.